# How to solve a set of linear differential equations with initial conditions?

Tags: matlab, equation

Given a matrix V to be and (W transpose) `Wt=`, find X'= V*X + W by solving the set of linear differential equations with initial conditions to be `Xi(0)=1` for `1<=i<=7`.

Attempt for solution:
I have used the MATLAB command dsolve

```
>> syms x1(t) x2(t) x3(t) x4(t) x5(t) x6(t) x7(t)
>> V=[2 3 4 5 6 0 7; 3 6 2 1 3 5 4; 4 2 2 4 2 7 5; 5 1 4 3 5 2 1; 6 3 2 5 4 1 2; 0 5 7 2 1 8 0; 7 4 5 1 2 0 9];
>> W=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]';
>> x=[x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6;x7];
>> S=dsolve(diff(X)==V*x+W,x1(0)==1,x2(0)==1); %the initial conditions give errors
>> x1=S.x1; x2=S.x2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
S=dsolve(diff(X)==V*x+W,x1(0)==1,x2(0)==1);
```

should read

```
S=dsolve(diff(x)==V*x+W,x(0)==[1;1;1;1;1;1;1])
```

however it is **very** slow for more than 2 variables. Numerical solutions will probably be just as useful, and far, far quicker to calculate.

(For reference, here is the solution for `x1` in the system with just `x1` and `x2`: `exp(-t*(13^(1/2) - 4))*((exp(t*(13^(1/2) - 4))*(2*13^(1/2) - 13))/78 + (13^(1/2)*(4*13^(1/2) - 17))/78) + exp(t*(13^(1/2) + 4))*((17*13^(1/2))/78 - (exp(-t*(13^(1/2) + 4))*(2*13^(1/2) + 13))/78 + 2/3)`, and this is only 2 out of 7 variables!)

Comment: Are you referring to ode45 for a quicker calculation?

Comment: @ASH yep `ode45` or similar